# Adding tooltip content dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know the premise of the jQuery tooltip widget is that a HTML element that has a tooltip bound to it has to exist before the tooltip function can be called, and so this snippet would work:

```
$('#test').append('<span id="testspan" title="My test span">Hello world</span>");
$('#testspan').tooltip();
```

However, I'm creating a whole HTML section by looping through some json, and then appending the whole section to my page. Each record I create has some spans I'd like to add some custom content too, using the [`content`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-content) argument. Using the following pseudo code won't work because the element doesn't exist when I call `.tooltip()`:

```
// parse JSON
/*
   ...
*/

// add results to page
var html;
for (var i=0; i<json_output.length; i++) {
  html+='<span id="' + i + '">' + json_output[i][0].val + '</span>';
  $('#' + i).tooltip({content: "Some complicated stuff from " + json_output[i][1].val + " that can't be in a title attribute"});
}

$('#mycontent').append(html);
```

I could call `append` within my loop - but I guess there are performance implications for this, or I could store the data in a separate array, and loop through it all and create all the tooltips after the `.append()` call - but this doesn't feel very clean. Is there a way of using a callback function (or similar) to set the `content` argument?

Comment: Why not you are using same class name for all tooltip and then call $(".classname").tooltip();

Comment: Sory, I should have made it clearer that the tooltip content is also unique - have updated the question to reflect this

Comment: I think you have to use $("#"+i).tooltip(...

Comment: @RakeshSojitra yes, that would be the correct syntax, but it does't solve the issue

Comment: What is the size of your JSON? Appending in the loop shouldn't have a performance issue (I have appended 500 rows to a table one by one in a project and never had any issue).

Comment: @BramVanroy - each of my records has got 10 html elements, of which 4 are spans which will have a tooltip applied to them.  There could be about 500 records in total - so about the same amount of HTML as your project I guess. It's reassuring to hear that it could be a viable solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution will work for your case, using the jQuery element data storage:

```
var $mycontent = $('#mycontent');
for( var i = 0; i < json_output.length; i++ ){
    var $item = $('<span class="mytooltip" id="' + i + '" title="">' + json_output[i][0].val + '</span>');
    $item.data('content', json_output[i][1].val);
    $mycontent.append($item);
}

$('.mytooltip').tooltip({ 
    content: function(){
        return $(this).data('content');
    }
});
```

Note: I'm not sure but I think that `.tooltip()` elements must have the title attribute (even empty).

Comment: This still relies on an `.append()` call within the loop tho, which is what I was a little concerned about.

Comment: I thought you just wanted an efficient way to add tooltips to the content. Think that at some time you'll have to append the items. See *[this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5moh1699/)*; it's another way to do the same appending all at the same time. But if you think your navigator will freeze for a while (we talk about too much data, a lot of data) maybe you'll need to use a worker or some method to add the data asynchronously.